# Using a cascading drop down on the same aspx page as an update panel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0. I have 2 `DropDownList`'s, a `CascadingDropDown` (from Ajax Control Toolkit) and an `UpdatePanel` on the same page.

The drop downs are not within the update panel, and their functionality is working fine (once one option is selected from a `DropDownList`, the `CascadingDropDown` does its thing and updates the second `DropDownList`).

The update panel simply contains a button and a text box. When the button is clicked, an event handler is in place to set the text on the text box.

The update panel works fine when the portion of code with the drop downs in is commented out, but as soon as the drop downs are uncommented, the clicking the button no longer refreshes the text box, no post back occurs.

The aspx page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<div>
    <label for="<%= ddOne.ClientID %>" >DD one</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOne" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="-1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option one" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option two" Value="2" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option three" Value="3" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown 
        ID="ccdOne"
        runat="server"
        ParentControlID="ddOne"
        TargetControlID="ddTwo" 
        Category="Category" 

        ServicePath="SomeWebService.asmx"
        ServiceMethod="SomeWebMethod"
        EmptyText="None available"
        EmptyValue="-1"
        LoadingText="Loading..." />

<div>
    <label for="<%= ddTwo.ClientID %>">DD two</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddTwo" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upPanelOne">

    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:Button ID="aButton" runat="server" Text="Click me" onclick="aButton_Click" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOne" runat="server" />

    </ContentTemplate>


</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The code behind:

```
    protected void aButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtOne.Text = "Hello world";
    }
```

Any ideas?

**Notes:**

`UpdatePanel` on its own works fine

`DropDownList`s with cascading drop down works fine

When `DropDownList`s used on the same page as the update panel, but not in the update panel, the update panel stops working?

Comment: I saw you've found the cause of the error. Please, post your findings as an answer to this question and accept it as the answer. Doing this can help other pleople with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add following tags to your `updatepanel`

```
<Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="aButton" EventName="Click" /
        </Triggers>
```

So it should be something like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upPanelOne">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="aButton" EventName="Click" /
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="aButton" runat="server" Text="Click me" onclick="aButton_Click" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOne" runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: As the button is a child control within the update panel I didn't think I needed to add the trigger explicitly like that... but I tried it any way and just like before, it works when the code for the DropDownList's is commented out, but when that code is on their it does not work :(

Comment: Ok I figured out what the problem was. Apparently if you add an element to a server control drop down list via javascript on postback you will get an exception thrown telling you to turn off event validation or some such message. It just seemed like nothing was happening because I was using an update panel so I was never seeing the error message. See: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/03/20/asp-net-event-validation-and-invalid-callback-or-postback-argument.aspx for details

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I followed the Ben comment which tells to set the `EnableEventValidation="false"` have cleared my issue and it's now working fine.